# Kotlin - pass dynamic type to a method

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a method in kotlin (I will use a simple version here)

```
  private fun checkMissing(input: InputType) {
    input.name=do something
    }
```

I have 2 classes:
InputType and InputType1.

```
 data class InputType1(
 override var name: String?,
  ..
 ): ExternalClass

 data class InputType1(
 override var name: String?,
  ..
 ): ExternalClass
```

InputType1 and InputType2, have a common field `name`,that I want to reassign, but the rest of the input is different.
In my `checkMissing` method, I want to be able to pass InputType1 from one method call, and inputType2, from another method.

```
 fun method1(input: InputType1) { checkMissing(input)-> I want this to mutate the input values of InputType1 else }
 fun method2(input2: InputType2) {checkMissing(input2)-> here the same //smth else}
```

Is there a way to do it, without creating checkMissing separately for both input types?
As the method will need to override input.name in both InputTypes classes accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an interface that they both implement. (Alternatively, this could be an `open`, `abstract`, or `sealed` class instead of an interface.)

```
interface InputType {
    val name: String?
}

data class InputType1: InputType(
    override var name: String?,
    //...
)
```

Then make the parameter type of the `checkMissing` function the interface.

```
private fun checkMissing(input: InputType) {
    //do something with input.name
}
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified the version I have provided with. 
Both InputType1 and InputType2 inherit an external class where  name is present (which I then use In the checkMissing method to assign a value)
If I inherit from the interface as well as the class I am overriding name for, would that still work?

Comment: Is `name` a property of ExternalClass? If so, you only need to change the parameter type of `checkMissing` to `ExternalClass`.

Comment: So InputTypes are the class format that come as an input from the frontend. Then name, id and other values are filled.
In checkMissing then, I need to reassign name based on some logic. Then I will use that InputType to pass to another method that will query the database based on those values.
I call checkMissing() before I call the database changes, to mutate InputType with new values.
If I override it on external class, that won't override it on InputType

Comment: So you're saying that InputType1 is a subclass of InputType. InputType defines a `var name` that you need to modify. But InputType1 is also implementing an interface called `ExternalClass` that has other members that you need to use in the same `checkMissing` function?

Comment: InputType1 and InputType2 are two separate class. Both inherit from ExternalClass, so they both override the name property.
CheckMissing() is called from method1, and method2 with InputType1 and InputType2 respectively.  That function will mutate the `name`property.
I didn't want to duplicate checkmissing() with different types like `fun checkMissing(input:InputType1) and fun checkMissingSecond(input:inputType1) , because the logic inside is the same, so I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically specify what input type checkMissing takes. I'm sorry if I made it confusing!

Comment: You should be able to define it using the common supertype as the parameter type, then: `private fun checkMissing(input: ExternalClass)`. Any subclass of ExternalClass can be passed to `checkMissing` and `checkMissing` can access any member defined in `ExternalClass`.

Comment: But if I pass input:ExternalClass. and then in the checkMissing, I do input.name=smthnew, it says I can not override it because it is `val` in ExternalClass, and I am not allowed to change that to var.
When I inherit ExternalClass, I can override the value, but when I pass it, I cannot assign it a new value.

Comment: I see. Can you make a subclass of ExternalClass that overrides `name` to make it a `var` and use that subclass as the parent of your other classes? Then you can make that common intermediate parent the parameter for checkMissing.

Comment: “it is `val` in `ExternalClass`, and I am not allowed to change that to `var`” — that's vital information, worth adding to the question.

Comment: If ExternalClass is defined in Java, instead of overriding, the intermediate class should define a `setName` function. Kotlin will treat it as part of the property. But the `name` field in the super class would need to have protected access to be able to set it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you so so much!! 
I added another class that overrides just the name, and then inherited that class in the 2 others that I needed. 
I was a little unfamiliar with multi-level inheritances and if it would work, but it works great!
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that you always get either an `InputType` or an `InputType1` and nothing else, you can use a sealed class:

```
sealed class Input(open var name: String?)
data class InputType(override var name: String?) : Input(name)
data class InputType1(override var name: String?) : Input(name)

fun checkMissing(input: Input) {
    println(input.name)
}
```